# Reordering 3 Columns in Bootstrap for SEO

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help reordering columns in Bootstrap for SEO purposes using push and pull. The final output would be like the image below. Right now I only need to switch the Left Sidebar and Main Content on desktop view. I managed to do this using a bunch of divs and floats but I decided to give bootstrap a try. Thanks!

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-1 my-col">
        Main Content (Middle)
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-2 my-col">
        Left Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-3 my-col">
        Right Sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.my-col{
line-height: 40px;
color:white;
text-align:center;
font-size: 20px;
}

.col-1{background:red}
.col-2{background:blue}
.col-3{background:green}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.my-col{
    line-height: 80px;
}
}
```

Bootply http://www.bootply.com/slW117V1oH#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column ordering is the inbulit feature of bootstrap framework. For more information visit [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
    </div>
```

example here [codepen](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/VjOwjL)
enjoy :)